# Speed of comparing to null vs undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

I have just run a very simple JavaScript [performance test](http://jsperf.com/js-coerce-null) (don't ask why). The test declares a variable, but doesn't assign anything to it:

`var x;`

It then compares the speed of comparing the value variable to `null`, and to `undefined`, in other words:

`var y = (x == null);` and `var y = (x == undefined);`.

I was expecting the comparison with `undefined` to be the fasted. In fact it was nowhere near. The comparison with `null` was far and away the fastest, around 80% faster.

The results I've described above come from running the tests in Chrome (version 13). Running them in Firefox produces results far closer to what I would have expected (the comparison with `undefined` is faster than with `null`, albeit very marginally).

So, my question is what could the cause of this be? Why does Chrome seem to favour the comparison with `null` so greatly?

For quick reference, here's a screenshot of the results:

[image]

Comment: This is the quickest question that I have seen get +10 votes ever.

Comment: @James what if you had used === instead of ==?

Comment: `undefined` does not exist in most languages for a reason. It is a convenience (or at least it can be), but it comes at a price.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`null` is a reserved keyword which cannot be overriden, so when you are doing a comparison against null, all you have to do is a single comparison.

However, when you are checking against `undefined`, the engine must do a type lookup and then a comparison, meaning that it is actually slightly more demanding.

---

If you need to actually check to see if something is undefined, you should use

```
if(typeof notSet == "undefined"){ }
```

---

### Proof

Try it... and set something to `null` in your JavaScript console.

```
null = "will error";
// Errors with --> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

However, if you try and do it with undefined, it won't error. That is not to say that you can override `undefined`, because you can't, but that `undefined` is its own primitive type.

The only real similarity between null and undefined, is that they can both be coerced into a boolean false.

Comment: That makes sense, but why then does Firefox not show similar results to Chrome?

Comment: I can't answer that James. I have no idea. Presumably it would be differences in the internals of their respective JS engines. The same way that Chrome is a lot faster for some heavy JavaScript sites, yet slower on some other parts.

Comment: @Layke what if he had used `===` instead of `==`?

Comment: `undefined` can be overridden within a function scope, if a function argument is named `undefined`.  For example: `function foo(undefined) { console.log(undefined); }`

Answer (score 1):

if i think well, they are not the same. so you can't use null instead of undefined.

[typeof !== "undefined" vs. != null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null)

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing against the lookup of a variable called `undefined` (which returns an undefined value), so it's not doing what you were intending.

There are ways to check whether a variable is undefined. As the other posters have mentioned, `typeof x === 'undefined'` is one. (There's probably another possibility that is something like `hasOwnProperty('x')` executed on the global object, but that doesn't check the scope chain.)

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that this:

```js
 if (typeof this._minLat === 'undefined') {
   this._minLat = Math.min(...this.points.map(point => point.lat));
 }
 return this._minLat;
```

seems to be many times faster than this:

```js
 return  this._minLat || Math.min(...this.points.map(point => point.lat));
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: I ran a jsperf [test](https://jsperf.com/undefined-comparision/1), tested on chrome 64 and found opposite of your answer.