# jquery remove attr then add attr

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working for some code with [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) because I have many large images, the page is loading slowly , I tried any `lazy loading plugin`, but not work well with `bxslider`. So finally, I tried to write some code by myself.

I tried to do something, if the `div is visible`, `removeAttr data-style`, then add `addAttr style`. my code in **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUEQp/)** (Omitted code for `bxslider`):

```
<div class="bgAnchor" data-style="background:url('http://it.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fNewRiverGorgeBridge_ROW468427072.jpg') no-repeat;background-position:0px 0px;"></div>
<div class="bgAnchor" data-style="background:url('http://it.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fPalmFrond_ROW2095872384.jpg') no-repeat;background-position:0px 0px;"></div>
<div class="bgAnchor" data-style="background:url('http://it.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fJacksonSquare_ROW1364682631.jpg') no-repeat;background-position:0px 0px;"></div>
<div class="bgAnchor" data-style="background:url('http://it.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fAustraliaClouds_ROW1600390948.jpg') no-repeat;background-position:0px 0px;"></div>​
```

```
$('.bgAnchor').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        var data_style = $(this).attr('data-style');
        if(data_style!== 'undefined' && data_style!== false){
            var attr_image = $(this).attr("data-style");
            $(this).css('background',attr_image).removeAttr("data-style");
        }
    }
});​
```

but I am not sure why it is not work. I am pleasure if any one can help me. many thanks.

Comment: `data_style!== 'undefined'` should be `data_style !== undefined` or `typeof data_style!== 'undefined'` if you like obnoxiously ugly code.

Comment: If you're running that code at $(document).ready() it's probably not triggering until the document is finished loading all the way.

Comment: ...and your jsFiddle is loading `MooTools` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: ...and if you're setting the entire style, then you should use `.attr('style',attr_image)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[from jQuery css() page](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. 
For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, 
use: $(elem).css('marginTop') 
and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on.
```

**this means that you can't use background in css()**

so you have to do it with style attribute.

```
 $(this).attr('style',attr_image);
```

[here is jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/qUEQp/7/)

Comment: thanks for a teach, btw, this also loading all the image when page loading, why `is(":visible")` not working?

Comment: @Giberno, because all divs are visible, there is no properties to make them nonvisible in your jsFiddle example. They **don't** have a CSS _display_ value of _none_ and their _width_ and _height_ are **not** explicitly set to **0**, so all divs are visible, you can look [here](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) how :visible selector working.

Comment: @Giberno, and look at the first div which has a display value of none in [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUEQp/11/), you can see that is(":visible") is working.

Comment: sorry, my mind is a bit confusion, my purpose is when the image enter the screen visible area, `replace` the `attr`, may be should use `div position` to make this judge.

Answer (score 1):

`.css()` only works for one property at a time, you've got 3, try using the style attribute; Undefined isn't a string, it's a built-in variable; and you don't need to get the `data_style` twice.

Try this:

```
$('.bgAnchor').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        var data_style = $(this).attr('data-style');
        if(data_style!== undefined && data_style!== false){
            $(this).attr('style',data_style).removeAttr("data-style");
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two things going on:

1) You should be checking for it being undefined using the `typeof` function in javascript, like so:

```
$('.bgAnchor').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        var data_style = $(this).attr('data-style');
        if(typeof data_style!== 'undefined' && data_style!== false){                   
            var attr_image = $(this).attr("data-style");
            alert(attr_image);
            $(this).css('background', attr_image).removeAttr("data-style");
        }
    }
});
```

(for a good explanation of why, see [this answer about typeof](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2703102/870729)

2) You're trying to pass too much into the "background" style with the `$(this).css('background', attr_image)` call.  So, you need to alter you data-style attribute as follows:

```
<div class="bgAnchor" data-style="url('http://it.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fNewRiverGorgeBridge_ROW468427072.jpg') no-repeat"></div>
```

If you want to set background-position, etc, you can either do that in your css for ALL .bgAnchor elements, OR you can add a new data-style for background-position, but you can't cram both background-position and background into the background css property.

Comment: take of your advice, update my code `http://jsfiddle.net/qUEQp/10/` why still loading all the images when open the page? why `is(":visible")` not working? thanks.

Comment: In the jsfiddle example you sent, the div's are visible due to display: block;  - if you want them to be not visible, set them to display: none, then the jQuery is(":visible") will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$(this).css('background',attr_image)
```

Your var `attr_image` (which BTW you don't need, it's identical to `data_style`) is the following string (for 1st div):

```
background:url('http://it.bing.com/az/hprichbg?p=rb%2fNewRiverGorgeBridge_ROW468427072.jpg') no-repeat;background-position:0px 0px;
```

The easiest solution is to use this:

```
this.style = attr_image;
```

The other solution is to put your style properties into separate `data-` attributes, one for `background`, another one for `background-repeat`, and yet another one for `background-position`. In this case, your `data-` attributes should contain only the values, not the CSS property names.