# Jquery select all elements that have $jquery.data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Select elements that i have previously set with `jquery.data();`

i.e. Select all elements with `.data('myAttr')` already been set.

**SOLUTION**

A jsfiddle to demostrate is  **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/argiropoulostauros/xynZA/3/)**

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You could do

```
$('[data-myAttr!=""]');
```

this selects all elements which have an attribute `data-myAttr` which is not equal to '' (so it must have been set); (only for elements that have their data attribute set in HTML not via jQuery)

you could also use [*filter()*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (which works for data attributes set from jQuery)

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('myAttr') !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: Or just: `$('[data-myAttr]')`

Comment: Thought the same thing. It doesn't work as expected. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gbHFZ/2/) DEMO

Comment: a closing ' is missing in the first piece of code (can't edit the answer directly)

Comment: $('[data-myAttr!=""]'); will return elements that do not have it assigned. @NULL 's comment only gets elements that have it set.

Comment: WRONG! correct solution : $('[data-myAttr]') -- see the answer below for explanation

Answer (score 81):

**The best and simple way to select them is:**

```
$('[data-myAttr]')
```

**More Information:**

I tested a lot of things.

Using `$('[data-myAttr!=""]')` doesn't work for all cases. Because elements that do not have a `data-myAttr` set, will have their `data-myAttr` equal to `undefined` and `$('[data-myAttr!=""]')` will select those as well, which is incorrect.

Comment: This only works with data attributes defined in the markup. It does NOT work with data attributes defined via jQuery, see https://jsfiddle.net/2p7h0Lj8/1/

Answer (score 22):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var elements = $("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("myAttr") !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: Was about to post this, here's a fiddle to show it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gbHFZ/1/

Comment: Why attribute selector doesn't do the job? `$('[data-myAttr]')` ?

Comment: @gdoron, that's because `data()`'s getter form does indeed read the HTML5 `data-` attributes, but its setter form neither creates nor updates them.

Comment: ummm, so where does it save the data? can you give my a reference? I read this _"(all data values are then stored internally in jQuery)."_ but where???

Comment: I have been thinking about the "undefined" check.. I have read that proper way would be 'typeof n !== "undefined"'. Is that check what you're using actually the same but shorter?

Comment: @gdoron, the data is persisted in a global cache, keyed by an id which is associated with the element through an expando property.

Comment: So how can I reach that data without `.data()`?

Comment: @Tx3, the `typeof x !== "undefined"` pattern is useful to check undeclared variables (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null). This is overkill here, since we're not working with a variable that might be undeclared.

Comment: @gdoron, you cannot do that without reproducing part of jQuery's internal implementation details. But why would you want to access information registered by the setter form of `data()` without using its getter form?

Comment: It was great, helped me a lot. Thanks for best answer.

Answer (score 19):

You could use this jQuery Selector extention: [Querying element data](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/)

```
$(':data');       // All elements with data  
$(':not(:data)'); // All elements without data
```

Comment: jQuery UI has this already so some may not need to call the anonymous function. http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/

Answer (score 9):

You can use JQuery UI with the [:data() selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/)

> Selects elements which have data stored under the specified key.

Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devconcept/2r2c6ku1/1/) for an example

To get all elements matching `.data('myAttr')` you can use

```
var matches = $(':data(myAttr)');
```

This should work for both elements with `data-` attributes and elements with data stored using `$.data()` because

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.

But this doesn't work very well. Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devconcept/z27n92jm/) and you will see that the second time the selector is called it should match 2 elements and is only matching one. This is due to "a bug" in the jquery-ui library.

This is taken from the core jquery-ui file.

```
 $.extend( $.expr[ ":" ], {
    data: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function( dataName ) {
            return function( elem ) {
                return !!$.data( elem, dataName );
            };
        }) :
        // support: jQuery <1.8
        function( elem, i, match ) {
            return !!$.data( elem, match[ 3 ] );
        }
});
```

As you can see they are using `$.data(elem, match)` instead `$(elem).data(match)` which causes the cache not to be updated in case you are requesting elements with `data-` attributes. If the element has been tested for `data()` storage this works well but if not it will not be included in the resulting matches.

This might not be a bug at all if what you want is to match only elements with data information set by you but if not you are left with two options.

1. Don't use jquery-ui and extend your own pseudo-selector `$(:mydata(myAttr))`

   ```
   $.extend($.expr[":"], {
      mydata: $.expr.createPseudo ?
      $.expr.createPseudo(function(dataName) {
         return function(elem) {
            return !!$(elem).data(dataName);
         };
      }) : function(elem, i, match) {
          return !!$(elem).data(match[3]);
      }
   });
   ```

   ```js
    // pseudoselector code
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
      mydata: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function(dataName) {
          return function(elem) {
            return !!$(elem).data(dataName);
          };
        }) : function(elem, i, match) {
          return !!$(elem).data(match[3]);
        }
    });
    // end pseudoselector

    testSelector = function() {
      var matched = $(':mydata(test)'),
        results = $('#results');
      results.append('<div>You matched ' + matched.length + ' elements</div>');
      matched.css('border', 'black 3px solid');
      console.log(matched);
      console.log('You matched ' + matched.length + ' elements');
    };

    testSelector();
    $('#addData').click(function() {
      $(".bar").data('test', 'value2');
      testSelector();
    });
   ```

   ```css
    .foo {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
    .bar {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }
    #addData {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
   ```

   ```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
      <span class="bar">without data attribute</span>
      <span class="foo" data-test="value1">with data attribute</span>
    </div>
    <button id="addData" type="button">Add data</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
   ```
2. Use jquery-ui with the `:data` pseudoselector and join the results of selecting `[data-myAttr]` to include the ones that might be skipped

   ```
   var matches = $(':data(myAttr)', '[data-myAttr]')
   ```

   ```js
    testSelector = function() {
      var matched = $(':data(test), [data-test]'),
          results = $('#results');
      results.append('<div>You matched ' + matched.length + ' elements</div>');
      matched.css('border', 'black 3px solid');
      console.log(matched);
      console.log('You matched ' + matched.length + ' elements');
    };

    testSelector();
    $('#addData').click(function() {
      $(".bar").data('test', 'value2');
      testSelector();
    });
   ```

   ```css
    .foo {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
    .bar {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }
    #addData {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
   ```

   ```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div>
      <span class="bar">without data attribute</span>
      <span class="foo" data-test="value1">with data attribute</span>
    </div>
    <button id="addData" type="button">Add data</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
   ```

Comment: This was part of the solution to my problem of selecting elements with data-* attributes without knowing the actual id or data attribute name. I found the way to extend jQuery to do this, elsewhere, but +1 here for the code snippet to show practical application. Others give just enough to hint, but sometimes you need to SHOW how to USE the information provided. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

```
$('[data-myAttr]').each(function() {
       var element = $(this);
       // Do something with the element
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> <strike>Select elements that i have previously set with `jquery.data();`</strike>

---

> The question is for finding all elements with a specific key and not
>   any data.

---

Try utilizing [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```js
$(".myClass").each(function(i){
    if( i % 2 == 0 ){
        $(this).data("myAttr",i + 1);                
    }
});
    
var res = $(".myClass").map(function(i) {
    console.log($(this).data("myAttr"));
    return $.data(this, "myAttr") !== undefined ? this : null
});    

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
<div class="myClass">4</div>
<div class="myClass">5</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xynZA/142/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The question is for finding all elements with a specific key and not any data.

Comment: @ArgiropoulosStavros Is requirement to return elements that have `html` `data-*` attribute set , as well as `jQuery.data()` set ?