# Check if a Cookie exists or not?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to find out if a cookie exists or not, if it doesn't I want to create it. I am doing this in Internet Explorer and its stopping at if(readCookie(count) == null) of the code below.

```
if(readCookie("count") == null)
{
    createCookie("count", 0, 10);
}


function readCookie(name) 
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) 
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does "stopping at" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check cookie if cookie exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968196/check-cookie-if-cookie-exists) (or at least that might have some code you can use).

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: stopping at means it doesn't execute an following lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `undefined` instead of `null`

See the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/D38WM/1/

Tested on both IE and FireFox

Here's a Stack Overflow link for more info:

[typeof !== "undefined" vs. != null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null)

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $.cookie('query') == null ) { 
    createCookie("count", 0, 10);
}
```

Comment: Probably an old post now but (if I understand you correctly) why does it need a jQuery tag inparticular, the plugin allows users to use the $ symbol in place jQuery a bit like PrototypeJS's selectors.