# Difference between != null and !== null in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Splitting hair here, but my editor complains I should use `a !== null` instead of `a != null` in a Javascript `if` statement. What is the difference?

**Update**

This question has been closed as duplicate, but the other questions supposedly answering my question are not answering it... Check their answers! There is a subtlety here -> `null`

Comment: That compairs also the type. However I'm not sure why this should be important for null

Comment: `!=` compare value, `!==` compares value AND type.

Comment: @rekire because `undefined==null` but `undefined!==null`

Comment: @nbrooks ah I see... `typeof(undefined)=="undefined"` and `typeof(null)=="object"`.

Comment: I think nbrooks comment deserves a real answer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null