# How safe is it to overload a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have:

```
function myFunk(param1) {
    if (param1) {
            // do stuff
    } 
}
```

and I alter this to ...

```
function myFunk(param1, param2) {
    if (param2) {
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

param2 can only ever be true or false. Is this safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe" ?

Comment: And what do you mean with "overload" ? You're changing the function, not overloading it.

Comment: See [Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456177/function-overloading-in-javascript-best-practices)

Comment: Well that will work but its not overloading its replacing one function with another.

Comment: Functions can't be overloaded in JavaScript because the arguments are typeless. Also, you may define a function with say 2 args, but you can pass more/less than 2 args and it won't fail. So what you are doing is replacing the same function with a new definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function myFunk(param1, param2) {
>     if (param2) {
>             // do stuff
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> param2 can only ever be true or false.

No. It can have any value. If the function is called with only one argument (`myFunk("something")`), then the `param2` will have the value `undefined`. Which is falsy (like `null`, `""`, `0` or `NaN`) of course, so as expected your if-statement will not be executed.

> Is this safe?

It's the standard way to have optional arguments in JavaScript, yes. For further details see [Function overloading in Javascript - Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/456177/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I feel it would be more clear if you use function variable approach.

```
var myFunk = function(param1) {
    if (param1) {
            // do stuff
    } 
}

and I alter this to ...

myFunk = function(param1, param2) {
    if (param2) {
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

It is now very clear what is happening, and the previous version of function myFunc does not exist anywhere.

**edit** more info

If you call `function(param1, param2) {}` with only one parameter, then `typeof param2 == "undefined"` will return true. For example:

```
myFunk = function(param1, param2) {
    if (typeof param2 == "undefined") {
        // do stuff with only param1
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use `param2 === undefined` rather than the string version of it.

Comment: No... `typeof` returns a string. This is safe for the case that `undefined` is redefined.

Comment: which is why i dropped the `typeof` from my code.

Comment: That's a terrible reason to drop it. Using typeof is the accepted way to test for define-ness

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null

Comment: I think he meant "altering the code" instead of "overwriting with a second definition"

Comment: Who knows what OP meant. A question this vague deserves to be closed.

Comment: yes see `undefined` is maybe surprisingly always defined, and if you have misspell your parameter I would prefer an error rather than a silent failure.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean.

Comment: if you had `typeof para2 == "undefined"` will be always be false where as it should be an error since you have misspelt `param2`. `undefined` is global so always exists (although it can be redefined).

Comment: And that would be your own damn fault. Same thing would happen if you typo the variable name *anywhere*

Comment: +1, for the excellent explanation why overloading isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload functions in javascript. you would be better checking the `arguments` or checking for `undefined` in order to see what the caller is trying to do. for example

```
function myFunk(param1, param2) {
    if (param2) {
            // do stuff
    }
}

myFunk(1); // if does not execute

myFunk(1, 2); // if executes
```

however if you pass a falsy value for the second param then the if will still not execute

```
myFunk(1,0);  // if does not execute
```

Answer (score -1):

Function overloading is not possible in javascript, if you made two same name function in same scope, always last function with that name will be called irrespective of number of parameters.

Comment: Downvote ??? any reasons...

Comment: I'd like to know as well, for my answer too.

Comment: Well if someone asks that is not feasible in a language, you can only say that's not possible. Any further explanation is waste of time to be specific

Comment: Yep I got randomly down-voted too. :-(