# "undefined" in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am using javascript function where i need to check undefined value in if condition.

```
var a = getParameterByName('a');
// if condition comes true only then below line should be executed. 
// but everytime either condition is true or false, below statement is executed.
if (typeof (a) !== "undefined") { 
    document.getElementById("img1").src = getParameterByName('a');
}
if (typeof getParameterByName('d') !== "undefined") {
    document.getElementById("video").src = getParameterByName('d');
}
```

is there any problem in using 'undefined' ?? 
please help me as soon as posssible. Thanks

Comment: just check `a != undefined`.possibly your `a` is `null`

Comment: Are you sure `a` is `undefined`? It could be `null`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5076962/1915855

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: You're probably just looking for if(a). No need for typeof undefined check.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null

Comment: `if (typeof a === "undefined")` ?

Comment: Show the code for `getParameterByName`

Answer (score 0):

it might look like `var a = getParameterByName('a');`
is getting value `a = '';`.

In javascript `'' != undefined` so check type of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Very inefficient code.

Try this. Src will be changed if a is none of `false`, empty string, `null`, `undefined` or `0`
It will not work as expected if a can be `1`, `true` or some string not a known image type. Pragmatically I assume the `getParameterByName` will return "image.gif" or "image.jpg" or one of the falsy values I described

```
var a = getParameterByName('a'); 
if (a) document.getElementById("img1").src = a;
```

Comment: What if the value of `a` is `false`?

Comment: Then there is still no reason to change an image source to false