# jQuery "undefined" if statement still outputting undefined matches

Tags: jquery, if-statement, undefined

I'm using jQuery to scan a page, find all the links on the page, and if they have a "title" attribute, output them in the console log.

```
$("a").each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    if (title !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(title + 'blah');
    }
})
```

What I cannot understand is that it outputs "undefined" many times as well, despite me specifying that it should not log anything with this value:

```
if(title !== 'undefined'){
    console.log(title+'blah');
}
```

Here is an example of the console.log results:

```
undefinedblah
About WordPressblah
undefinedblah
comments awaiting moderationblah
Newblah
undefinedblah
My Accountblah
undefinedblah
```

Why are all these `undefined` options passing my `if` statement?

Comment: The **value** `undefined` is different from the **string** `"undefined"`. Or are you *literally* having `titel="undefined"` in your HTML?

Comment: @FelixKling how can I express the `undefined` value correctly in this if statement?

Comment: `title !== undefined`

Comment: possible duplicate of [typeof !== "undefined" vs. != null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
if(title){
    console.log(title+'blah');
}
```

It checks for truthy value. The value is `undefined` and not `'undefined'`

> `title` would be *falsy* under `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""` and `false`

---

Side note, why not use *attribute selector*; it would omit the `a`s without `title`

```
$("a[title]").each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    console.log(title + 'blah');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly check that the type is not undefined use `typeof`. At the moment you are checking that the type of variable is "string" and its value is "undefined".

```
if(typeof title !== "undefined") {
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `"undefined"` use `undefined`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div a").each(function () {
        var value = $(this).prop("title");
        console.log(value);
        if (value !== undefined) console.log("title: "+value);
    });
});
```

For more information check this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_undefined.asp).