# What is meaning of "typeof $" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is meaning of **typedef $** in following source code. I have read from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null).

typeof allows the identifier to never have been declared before. So it's safer in that regard:

But here they are using  `if (typeof $ !== 'undefined')`, what is meaning of `$` here.

I copied following code from [this link](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/metering/templates/metering/stats.html#L168-#L200)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof horizon.d3_line_chart !== 'undefined') {
    //alert("test1");
    //When first time It give alert means it is defiend 
    horizon.d3_line_chart.init("div[data-chart-type='line_chart']",
      {'auto_resize': true});
  }

  if (typeof $ !== 'undefined') {
    //alert("alert2");
    /*
      We first time we run resource usage, then It will show alert, and date options are not showing. So means first time It hides the date options. Means '$' varaible is defined.
    */
   show_hide_datepickers();
  } else {
    addHorizonLoadEvent(function() {
      show_hide_datepickers();
    });
  }

  function show_hide_datepickers() {
    $("#date_options").change(function(evt) {
        // Enhancing behaviour of selectbox, on 'other' value selected, I don't
        // want to refresh, but show hide the date fields
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "other"){
          evt.stopPropagation();
          $("#date_from input, #date_to input").val('');
          $("#date_from, #date_to").show();
        } else {
          $("#date_from, #date_to").hide();
        }
    });
    if ($("#date_options").find("option:selected").val() == "other"){
      $("#date_from, #date_to").show();
    } else {
      $("#date_from, #date_to").hide();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Certainly to ensure JQuery (Or another library?) is loaded and bind to `$`

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue ,  Thanks for reply, and what is meaning of  `typeof horizon.d3_line_chart !== 'undefined'`

Comment: check if the horizon.d3_line_chart class was included or not

Comment: Same, it's just testing if `horizon.d3_line_chart` is defined.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue, `horizon.d3_line_chart`  this is  horizon.d3_line_chart.js file, what I did I remove the source code of it, and run this program. It still executing if condition, why?

Comment: @JeremyC. ` horizon.d3_line_chart`  this is  horizon.d3_line_chart.js file, what I did I remove the source code of it, and run this program. It still executing if condition, why?

Comment: if you are in chrome or firefox hit ctrl+f5 also check if you're not including the .js file anywhere else

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, `$` is just a variable name so:

```
if (typeof $ !== 'undefined')
```

is just checking to see if the `$` variable is already defined or not.  In code that uses jQuery, the `$` sign is usually an alias for the `jQuery` object so this code would be checking to see if jQuery was present or if jQuery was using the `$` symbol or not.

You don't show us the `addHorizonLoadEvent()` code, but logic would suggest that maybe it is responsible for loading jQuery or for knowing when a set of stuff that includes jQuery has finished loading and it is used if the code finds that whatever loads `$` has not yet finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the author is just checking if some libraries are present and loaded :

- `(typeof $ !== 'undefined')` --> A library using `$` (JQuery in your case)
- `(typeof horizon.d3_line_chart != 'undefined')` --> A chart library?

This allow to do some code if a library was loaded and don't crash if it wasn't. Could also be used to be able to use different library, if one isn't present try another.