# Check if checkbox defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check if a checkbox is defined and unchecked it. On load my checkbox is disabled and I am getting the error that is undefined. I try to put a condition to avoid the error but didn't work

```
 if ( typeof $scope.user.test !== 'undefined')
    {
        $scope.user.test = false;
    }

 <md-checkbox ng-model="user.test" layout="row" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">
      Test
 </md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Why not preset it to false?

Comment: Show your input field.

Comment: In one line $scope.user.test = $scope.user.test ? false : true;

Comment: Where exactly do you want me to put that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/h2t3K0Fwxpo5gAhAeqqt?p=preview here is working plunker.
You may forgot to include all the below dependencies.
Now you can do your work.

```
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript">
         angular
            .module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('checkBoxController', checkBoxController);

         function checkBoxController ($scope) {    
             $scope.call = function(){
                 alert($scope.user.test)  
             }
         }  
      </script>      
   </head>
   <body ng-app="firstApplication" ng-controller="checkBoxController">  
      <md-checkbox ng-model="user.test" ng-change="call()" aria-label="No Ink Effects">
         Check
      </md-checkbox>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, he is comparing the type of `$scope.user.test` to `"undefined"`, which is correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null

Comment: Thank you . I changed it. The same issue.